# Is possible to use a common session variable for flex and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, session-variables

I have an asp website which has a page embeded with swf file.The swf file is build using flex. I want to set a value in a session variable in flex and later use this session variable in asp to retrieve value.

Or is there any method to know changes made in flex(swf file) at asp side.
Note that swf file has a grid in which data change occur.

Comment: How is Flex integrated with ASP? You mean that Flex communicates w/ services created in ASP or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either of these:

> - Assign change to a hidden variable in web page.
> - Query the variable at server side in ASP .Net. And put it in session.

Or

> - When you want to change any thing in Session, just call the webservice from JavaScript which should change value in Session(or do whatever you want to do in server).

See how you can [call ASP.Net WebService from flex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37649/Flex-Communication-with-ASP-NET-WebService).

Comment: I tried as shown in the above link you provided. But control not going to the service page.

Comment: can you post the code where you are calling the web-service? (I would suggest work with a smaller example)

Comment: Thank you @Falaque.. I got it right with the above example provided in the link. I had forgot to right **?wsdl** after the localhost link wsdl="http://localhost/TestWebService/Service.asmx?WSDL"